# How to store ipv4 address and date into oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, date, ipv4

Hye, i'm new with oracle. I want to know how to store the ipv4 address in my database. and may i know why my date does not appear as the year 2013?

this is how i create the table

```
CREATE TABLE developer.FYP (
  id_user INT NOT NULL ,
  host_name VARCHAR2(255) ,
  ip_address VARCHAR2(255) ,
  last_login TIMESTAMP(0)  ,
  date_register DATE ,
  data VARCHAR2(255) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
)
  NOCOMPRESS;
```

and this is how i store the data

```
INSERT INTO developer.fyp VALUES (
    id_user_seq.nextval,
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','TERMINAL'),
    SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','IP_ADDRESS'),
    SYSDATE,
    TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    enc_dec.encrypt ('hello world')

    );
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you've circled an ipv6 address in your image and asking about an ipv4 address...? To know why your date appears wrong, please show your insert that sets the value to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

The IP Address being stored is likely a function of how you are requesting the IP Address from the underlying library, and is unlikely to be a database issue at all.

No one here will be able to give a good answer unless you can post the code being used to gather the data and perform the insert

Answer (score 0):

The circled data in your image is an IPV6 address not IPV4 address. For storing IP address you can use `VARCHAR`. IP address does not represent a number and you rarely do any math on it. So it is better to use **VARCHAR** to store IP Address.

> and may i know why my date does not appear as the year 2013?

To answer this please let us know how you are storing the date in your `DATE_REGISTER` column.

Comment: IPV4 address DOES represent a number.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the date is this;

```
INSERT INTO developer.fyp VALUES (
  ...
  SYSDATE,
  TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY'),
  ...
);
```

The `TO_DATE` will convert `SYSDATE` to a string and parse it back to a date, which will lose the 2 first digits of the year. Instead just do,

```
INSERT INTO developer.fyp VALUES (
  ...
  SYSDATE,
  SYSDATE,
  ...
);
```

...and the date will show up correctly.

The second problem - that you're getting an IPv6 address in your log - is due to the fact that *the client is actually connecting using IPv6 to Oracle*, and there is no IPv4 address to log. If you make the client connect via IPv4, you'll automatically log that instead.